# How do you output field changes in mysql the most efficiently?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a rather large employee feed coming in and each employee has about 50 fields.

I take the employee data and add on a bunch of other stuff and this gets outputted to one of our vendors.  Most of the outputted data is via Views where I take LDAP data and then other tables/views that my team does mapping.

So one of our vendors asked us can we just get the employees whose job_role has changed?  Well the job_role field is done through mapping on our Job_role_map View which uses the LDAP job_title field.

Is there a way that I can report in my final view when the job_role has changed?  So this could change via the main LDAP field or we could change the mapping for their job_title.

Main LDAP create

```
DROP TABLE
IF EXISTS testgiver.ldap_karen;

CREATE TABLE testgiver.ldap_karen (uid VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) 
SELECT
  ldap_full.uid as 'uid',
    ldap_full.xyznamedisplay,
    ldap_full.businesscategory,
    ldap_full.mail,
    ldap_full.givenname,
    ldap_full.sn,
  ldap_full.xyzjobcode,
    ldap_full.departmentnumber,
    ldap_full.title,
    ldap_full.xyzmgdescr,
    ldap_full.xyzmgdescroverride,
    ldap_full.xyzcompanydescr,
    ldap_full.xyzcompanydescroverride,
    ldap_full.xyzlocationstreet1,
    ldap_full.xyzlocationcity,
    ldap_full.xyzlocationstatedescr,
    ldap_full.xyzlocationpostal,
    ldap_full.xyzlocationcountry,
    ldap_full.xyzlocationcountrydescr,
    ldap_full.xyzsupervisorid,
    ldap_full.xyzsupervisoriddescr,
    ldap_full.xyzcompanyshortdescroverride,
            CASE
        WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Go To Market Europe-ALL' THEN 'F&R Go To Market Europe-ALL'
        WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Go To Market Americas-ALL' THEN 'F&R Go To Market Americas-ALL'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Go To Market Asia-ALL' THEN 'F&R Go To Market Asia-ALL'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Go To Market Strategic Customers & Solutions-ALL' THEN 'F&R Go To Market Strategic Customers & Solutions-ALL'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Go To Market Strategy & Operations-ALL' THEN 'F&R Go To Market Strategy & Operations-ALL'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Financial-ALL' THEN 'F&R Financial'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Finance - ALL' THEN 'F&R Financial'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Investors - ALL' THEN 'F&R Financial'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Trading - ALL (inactive)' THEN 'F&R Financial'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Marketplaces - ALL (inactive)' THEN 'F&R Financial'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE '%Risk%' THEN 'F&R Risk'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE '%GRC%' THEN 'F&R Risk'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Unified Platform Group-ALL' THEN 'F&R Unified Platform Group-ALL'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE 'F&R Content, Analytics & Valuation Srvs-ALL' THEN 'F&R Content, Analytics & Valuation Srvs-ALL'
        WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE '%GGO%' THEN 'GGO'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE '%News%' THEN 'abc'
                WHEN ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr LIKE '%abc%' THEN 'abc'
                ELSE 'Other'
      END as sa_bu,
    ldap_full.xyzbulevel1descr,
    ldap_full.xyzbulevel1shortdescr,
    ldap_full.xyzbulevel2descr,
    ldap_full.xyzbulevel2shortdescr,
    ldap_full.xyzroleindicatordescr,
    ldap_full.xyzjobcodedescr,
    ldap_full.xyzjobfamilycode,
    ldap_full.xyzjobfamilydescr,
    ldap_full.xyzrecordtypedescr,
    sup_email.mail AS supemail, 
  reports_regionnames.regionname,
  ldap_karen_helper1.sa_title

FROM
    ldap_full
LEFT JOIN ldap_karen_helper1 ON ldap_full.uid = ldap_karen_helper1.uid
LEFT JOIN ldap_full AS sup_email ON ldap_full.xyzsupervisorid = sup_email.uid
LEFT JOIN reports_regions ON ldap_full.xyzlocationcountrydescr = reports_regions.xyzlocationcountrydescr
LEFT JOIN reports_regionnames ON reports_regions.xyzregion1 = reports_regionnames.regiondid
```

Helper table for the table above

```
SELECT
ldap_full.xyzjobcodedescr,
reports_salesroles.jobroleid,
reports_jobroles.groupabrev AS sa_title,
ldap_full.mail,
ldap_full.uid,
ldap_full.xyzroleindicatordescr,
ldap_full.xyzsupervisorid
FROM
reports_salesroles
INNER JOIN reports_jobroles ON reports_salesroles.jobroleid = reports_jobroles.nameid
INNER JOIN ldap_full ON ldap_full.xyzjobcodedescr = reports_salesroles.xyzjobcodedescr
```

Job Role Mapping table - our admin team maps corporate job titles to job_roles.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reports_jobroles`;
CREATE TABLE `reports_jobroles` (
  `nameid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `groupname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `groupabrev` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `notes` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nameid`),
  KEY `rolename` (`nameid`,`groupname`,`groupabrev`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If you need more tables/examples let me know.  These are all pushed to views that just give employee data/role data that is spit out to vendors so that vendors can put people in buckets for whatever.

Comment: Could you add details describing the tables and views involved, etc?  Without something to go on, this is difficult to answer reliably. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxVernon - Adding now.

Comment: +5 hours; still no `SHOW CREATEs`

Comment: @RickJames - sorry was at work.  And you wouldn't believe that I don't have access to our main internet server at work!  (my home IP is whitelisted but we can't get a secure connect through corporate firewalls)